# Vim starts with garbage characters in command window

Tags: vim

Starting Vim produces some odd characters in the command window. Here's what's given to me:

:.2501;0c

I'm using the same .vimrc on two machines, one Ubuntu, one Scientific Linux, and only the one on Scientific Linux is acting in this way.

Anyone know anything about this? It's just quite annoying to have to delete these characters before getting down to work.

Comment: I suggest you debug this by (partially) commenting and uncommenting lines in your vimrc until the snag hits. If that doesn't show it, disable plugins and re-enable one-by-one.

Comment: Interestingly, changing my Ubuntu's $TERM to 'xterm' (as it is on S.L) produces a similar - although not identical - sequence of garbage characters.

Comment: `termcap`, `stty` and `vim -T` ... might be good leads to debug further. Did you establish whether `vim -u NONE` still has the problem?

Comment: It's a long shot, but it could be your .vimrc sets some terminal-related sequences like mine does. Check your .vimrc for settings like `let &t_XX = ...` (where `XX` is two or more characters). I have a couple of those in mine, to change the shape of the cursor depending on mode, but when I use vim with that .vimrc on a system/terminal that doesn't support cursor shape changes, the first time I hit `:` I get `:<left arrow>]50;CursorShape=0`.

Comment: Does <C-L> deletes these characters? If yes, add this command at the end of your .vimrc as a workaround: `autocmd VimEnter * redraw!`.

Comment: Does anybody know how to solve this issue? I still have the same issue under Ubuntu 18.04 terminal.